# Java -how can I make class Oval using the start point for their centre and control point for the edges of the shape?

Tags: java, graphics, shapes

As a Beginner in Java i have tried to write the following Oval class. I know there is error and so needed assistance in correcting.

```
public class Oval extends Shapes {
      private int upperLeftX;
      private int upperLeftY;
      private int width;
      private int height;


     public  Oval(Point startPoint){
        super( startPoint);
}
    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        int upperLeftX = Math.min(startPoint.x, controlPoint.x );
        int upperLeftY = Math.min(startPoint.y, controlPoint.y );
        int width = Math.abs(startPoint.x- controlPoint.x);
       int height = Math.abs(startPoint.y- controlPoint.y);

        g.setColor(getColour());   
        g.drawOval(upperLeftX, upperLeftY, width, height);
    }

}
```

Over here all what I am trying to do is use the start point for their centre and control point for the edges of the shape.

Comment: What error message are you getting? What do `Shapes`, `Point` and `Graphics` look like?

Comment: I guess you are shadowing `width`, `height` and so on with the local variables, but you have to provide us with more detailed error description.